# Multiple Devices login Details .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to show user that on how many devices user is currently
login

https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity like this,

I am using asp.net core Identity is there any solution for this using identity ?[image]